# Adding vertical space constraint equal to superview height multiple

Tags: ios, autolayout, storyboard, interface-builder, constraints

I want to achieve a very simple thing. I have a UIView, i want the vertical space between my UIView bottom and bottom layout guide to be 10% of the container height (in this case viewController.view). How can achieve this in storyboards?

So some thing like this

```
UIView.bottom = Height of superView * 0.1 + 0 from the Bottom layout guide
```

is there anyway to achieve this in storyboards. Currently i can just some constant magic number which will not work on iPhone 4s all the way till iPhone 6 plus.

Clicking on the constraint shows this properties, so how can i put something like superViewHeight * 0.1 in here. I understand that i can do this if i am setting the height of the view but how to do in this case.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: If you click on that bottom constraint, you will see constraint property window on right side where you can see a multiplier field. Use that for making proportional constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invert the first and second item in this case. Simply click on `first item` dropdown and you will see the option.

Secondly, give a value of `0.9` in `multiplier` section. That will make the gap 10% of total height.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a constraint in proportion to the superview's height and not the height of the view itself.

You can do this programmatically by creating an `NSLayoutConstraint` and specify it's `constant` an run time.

```
let marginToBottomLayout = customView.superview!.frame.size.height * 0.1
let constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customView,
    attribute: .Bottom,
    relatedBy: .Equal,
    toItem: self.bottomLayoutGuide,
    attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0,
    constant: marginToBottomLayout)
```